# Apply master page to the settings page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I created a new master page which I successfully applied to my site.
The problem is, the main of my page don't contain the settings page.
this is the master code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
    <div id="main_container">
       <div class="header row-fluid">
       </div> 
           <!--Need to show all my pages here -->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you applied this master page as the Site Master Page and System Master Page?

Comment: how to apply it as master page : I have done this with SharePoint designer. and for system master page how can I do it ?

Comment: Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862339(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I always have an unorganised page, in the default master page there is a div call :"ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" which contain the page.I don't know how to do it. Do I need to add all this div to my page, I am newer in SharePoint designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Site Master page**

This master page is used by all publishing pages in a site, so when we are working with publishing pages update this master pages.This is available as a property of the object SPWeb , you could access like SPWeb.CustomMasterUrl

You could update it by following powershell script

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myportalsite    
$web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/V4.master"
$web.Update()
```

**System Master Page**

This master page is used by all forms and view pages in this site. For example if you got home page of library (AllItems.aspx) this master page is used.This is available as a property of the object SPWeb , you could access like SPWeb.MasterUrl .

You could update it by following powershell script

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myportalsite/    
$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/SystemV4.master"    
$web.Update()
```