# Use both "System Master Page" AND "Site Master Page" on an teamsite

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, system-master-page

I want to use my custom masterpage as a site masterpage and keep the default "seattle" masterpage in the settings view ("System master page option").

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. If you open a page in SharePoint Designer you can see a MasterPageFile setting which can be modified:

   - "~masterurl/default.master": the page will use the system master page
   - "~masterurl/custom.master": the page will use the site master page
2. Additionally you can also set this through the UI, by navigating to the Site Collection Settings --> Look and Feel --> Master Page. Here you can choose the Site and System Master page separately.
3. Also, this can be done through Powershell,

I have posted that earlier here 
[Apply master page to the settings page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120131/apply-master-page-to-the-settings-page/120179#120179)

Comment: Tnx for the reply, but this doesn't work on teamsites though.. System master page effects everything when its a teamsite. I want the site settings overview to use seattle and sites to use my custom. Do you understand?

Comment: Understood. This cannot be done without enabling the publishing infrastructure feature first at the site collection and then at the site level. Then you can follow the steps above. After you are done, you can disable the publishing feature if required. The changes will be retained.

Comment: Tnx for the reply but this still doesen't make it possible to use different masterpages on site and system master pages. Guess its not possible then?

Comment: okej, I think I should try using a javascript instead. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to open the Site Settings -> Master Page and select

**Site Master Page** = Your custom master page

**System Master Page** = seattle

[image]

Comment: Tnx for the reply, but this doesn't work on teamsites though.. System master page effects everything when its a teamsite. I want the site settings overview to use seattle and sites to use my custom. Do you understand?